# Problem with filling a two-dimensional array in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to fill a two-dimensional array of int in c++.

But i have a weird problem.
Basically right now i have a code like that :

```
int array[83][86];
int test_1 = 0;
int test_2 = 0;
for (int x = box.min_corner().x(); x < box.max_corner().x(); x = x + 50)
{
    for (int y = box.min_corner().y(); y < box.max_corner().y(); y = y + 50)
    {
        point_t point_p(x, y);
            if (bg::within(point_p, poly))
            {
                array[test_1][test_2] = '1';
            }
            else {
                array[test_1][test_2] = '0';
            }
            test_2++;
    }
    test_1++;
}
```

My program crashes before all columns are filled. Basically my program stop column 58.
The problem is not my two for loops, because if I increase my array like this :
int array[83 * 2][86];
It continues normally, as it is supposed to work initially.

Anyone have an idea of what can trigger this issue ?

Comment: what is `box.min_corner()` and `box.max_corner()` ?

Comment: I prefer the terminology "two-dimensional array" or "2D array" to "double array".

Comment: @Wyck in my vocabulary, “double array” is `std::array<double, N>`, or possibly loosely defined as any contiguous storage of `double`. I avoid C-style “arrays”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reset `test_2` to `0` appropriately. Otherwise, you keep incrementing the variable and it eventually goes past the limit of `86`.